# mysqld throws error, ignores --tmpdir switch

Tags: mysql, cygwin

I'm using the MySql Server which comes with Cygwin. No matter whether I start it like this:

```
 mysqld --tmpdir=/cygdrive/c/temp start
```

or like this:

```
mysqld start --tmpdir=/cygdrive/c/temp
```

I always get the error message

```
151104 15:50:48 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.5.45) starting as process 8784 ...
151104 15:50:48 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/CMTCL033974.lower-test
151104 15:50:48 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/CMTCL033974.lower-test
```

It looks as if the `--tmpdir` option would be ignored.

BTW, the directory `/cygdrive/c/temp` exists and is writeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be easy: `--tmpdir` does not affect the location of *these* files. They always have to be under /var/lib, so I manually created /var/lib/mysql, and the error message disappeared.

However, `mysqld` now complains about the `start` parameter, but this is an unrelated issue, where I will open a separate thread for it, if I can't figure it out by myself....